# Alsa can't pipe arecord to aplay, ressource busy EDIROL UA-101

Tags: audio, alsa

I am trying to get both playback and capture stream on the same usb sound card. As of now, my `asoundrc` file look like this:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm ua101
    }
}

pcm.ua101 {
    type hw
    card 1
    device 0
}

ctl.ua101 {
    type hw
    card 1
    device 0
}
```

`aplay` and `arecord` are working fine separately, but a resource busy error pops up when trying to pipe `arecord` to `aplay`.

This behavior is reproducible in C code. Does Alsa have a way to initialize a duplex stream ?

As an alternate solution, would it be possible to create two different devices in .asoundrc, one for playback and one for capture, and implement the system in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alsa itself works fine with a duplex stream, I tried with my USB soundcard:

```
arecord -D plughw:CARD=UA25EX | aplay -D plughw:CARD=UA25EX -
```

just works (no special `asoundrc`).

So I'd assume that your USB soundcard for some reason only allows either playback or recording, but not both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got some help from the #alsa IRC guys, but we couldn't make it work. We concluded the same, the driver can't handle duplex mode.